# Ajax call doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following view, partial view and controller:

```
@using CustomersAJAX.Models
@model Tuple<List<Customer>, Customer>

@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "customerInfo"
    };

}

@using (Html.AjaxBeginForm("OnSelectCustomer", "Customer", ajaxOptions))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

    var selected = false;

    foreach (var customer in Model.Item1)
    {
        if (Model.Item2 == customer)
        {
            selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            selected = false;
        }

        @Html.RadioButton("CustomerNumber", customer.ID, selected);
        @Html.Label(customer.Name);
        <br />
    }
    <input type="submit" id="SumbitButton" value="Submit Details" />

}

<div id="customerInfo">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_CustomerDetails.cshtml", Model.Item2)
</div>

@model CustomersAJAX.Models.Customer

<h3>Customer Details</h3>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Name):@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Name)
<br />
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.Age):@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Age)
<br />
<p>Updated at @DateTime.Now</p>


public class CustomerController : Controller
{
        List<Customer> customers;

        public CustomerController()
        {
            customers = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer(0, "Sherry", 37),
                new Customer(1, "Tim", 12),
                new Customer(2, "Charlene", 98),
                new Customer(3, "Dane", 24),
                new Customer(4, "Elijah", 51),
                new Customer(5, "Howard", 64),
                new Customer(6, "Dave", 34)
            };
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Tuple<List<Customer>, Customer> tuple = new Tuple<List<Customer>, Customer>(customers, customers[0]);

            return View("Customer", tuple);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnSelectCustomer(string CustomerNumber)
        {
            return PartialView("_CustomerDetails", customers[int.Parse(CustomerNumber)]);
        }
}
```

It works, however, the Ajax part ('_CustomerDetails' view) renders as separate view like in case there was no Ajax, and not as part of the Customer view as it is supposed to do.

I have the following package installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax" Version="1.1.3" />
```

And in `_Layout.cshtml` body I reference the following:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check if your `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` exists in `wwwroot/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive`**. When you install the `AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax` server side library, it does not mean you also have installed the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` which is client side library in local.

If you just install the `AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax`, you can use `@Html.RenderUnobtrusiveAjaxScript()` to call the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Or you can [use Libman(which used to install client side library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog) to install `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in local:

[image]

---

**The whole working way** by using `AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax` should be like below:

1. Install `AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax` nuget package:

> PM> Install-Package AspNetCore.Unobtrusive.Ajax

2. Add Service and Middleware in Startup.cs:

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        services.AddUnobtrusiveAjax(); 
        //services.AddUnobtrusiveAjax(useCdn: true, injectScriptIfNeeded: false);
        //...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
    //...
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //It is required for serving 'jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js' embedded script file.
        app.UseUnobtrusiveAjax(); //It is suggested to place it after UseStaticFiles()
        //...
    }
   ```
3. Add Script Tag in _Layout.cshtml:

   ```
   <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <!--Place it at the end of body and after jquery-->

    @Html.RenderUnobtrusiveAjaxScript()

   <!-- Or you can reference your local script file -->

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I was completely missing part 2 and partially missing part 3